# Read data from a register in C

Tags: c, sdk, spi, vivado

I am a beginner and learning by myself.

I need to read data from SPI (FIFO). I have found an example.

1. Create a read and write buffers

```
// 10 is a number of bytes to be received by SPI 
u8 ReadBuffer[10];
u8 WriteBuffer[10];
```

2. Read function

```
#define SpiPs_RecvByte(BaseAddress)    \(u8)XSpiPs_In32((BaseAddress) + XSPIPS_RXD_OFFSET)
```

which I can use as follow

```
for(Count = 0; Count < ByteCount; Count++)
{
        ReadBuffer[Count] = SpiPs_RecvByte(Spi0.Config.BaseAddress);
}
```

Q1. Could someone explain how the function SpiPs_RecvByte works ( in detail)?

Q2. I have tested "XSpi_Transfer" in my simulaton as it used in an [example](https://github.com/Xilinx/embeddedsw/blob/master/XilinxProcessorIPLib/drivers/spi/examples/xspi_slave_intr_example.c). My compiler (SDK xilinx) is giving me the following warning: "implicit declaration of function". Why is it coming?

PS I use ZedBoard Zynq 7000

Thank you in advance for all your recommendation and information?

Comment: By "register", do you mean a range of memory addresses mapped to the device? As contrasted with a CPU register, which was my first take on what you are asking about?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Is there a difference in an implementation?

Comment: Between reading a CPU register and reading data from a device via a memory mapping?  I should say so.  Different instructions are required at the machine code level, and at the C level there is no way to express reading from a CPU register.  Reading from memory mapped to the device, on the other hand, requires only that one obtains a pointer to the appropriate address or a variable directly representing the device-mapped memory -- by implementation-defined means in either case.

Comment: @JohnBollinger is alluding to "memory mapped I/O", which would be a good read in this case and help you understand what's going on